# Is it possible to add int into the String ArrayList with out Converting int to String in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, casting

i have an `ArrayList` which contains `String` elements and i want to add an `int` into the `list` but with out Converting that into the String is that possible.

i have tried this and this is working too.

```
int a1 = 10;
java.util.List list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(a1);
System.out.println("List element"+list.get(0));
```

and but i am wondering this to be happen.

```
int a1 = 10;
java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(a1);
            System.out.println("List element"+list.get(0));
```

is that possible to do?

Comment: No.. You shouldn't do it.. You can add anything if the list is raw.. But still its not a good practice..

Comment: No it isn't, unless you have a `List<Object>` And even then you'd need to `.add(new Integer(a1))` since `int` is not a class.

Comment: What would be the point of having a list of strings (List<String>) if you can put anything inside it? The whole point of generics is to provide type-safety.

Comment: @fge that is not bad ans. actually its partially 90% right ans. :) so +1 for you.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
 list.add(String.valueOf(a1));
```

Answer (score 1):

An advantage of a typed list is, that you can assume, that you only have objects of the given type in the list - why would one want to throw this advantage away, if it is completely easy to convert the given type into the type of the list?

Comment: I agree dude but its just for knowledge any ways +1 for your ans. :)

Answer (score 1):

In first case your `List` is just a raw `List`. So you can add what ever type to that since `List` is raw and again that is bad way of use of `List` in `Java`..But second case it is `String` `List` you have to add Stings there.

Now you have to use following way to add `int` to `List`.

```
 int a1 = 10;
 java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add(String.valueOf(a1)); // now String value of int will add to list
 System.out.println("List element"+list.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it without converting it to String, but one alternate way to do it by String concatination(without direct conversion from int to String):

```
list.add("" + a1);
```

but internally it will append a1 value to "" String and final result is String.

Comment: It converting that value into the String it self bro. :) i dont want it. but ya +1 for your response.